# Symfony2: How to check and display javascript enabled/disabled on the website

Tags: javascript, symfony

I need to check if javascript is enabled or not on websites on every page. What is the best practice to consider apart from  html element? How is it done using symfony2 specifically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing todo with Symfony2 or any php framework or any server side language.

You just have to do it in your html layout.

The best practice is to always set your page to have javascript **disabled** and then to enable it.

It is commonly done by using this snippet.

```
<html class="no-js" ="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
      (function(H){H.className=H.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js');})(document.documentElement);
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does this snippet do? Can you please explain?

Comment: well, it basically sets the page with a "no-js" class, if javascript is enabled, the class name is replaced with "js". replace is a regex substitution called on <html> tag element.

Comment: oh ok. so the code checks js is enabled or not on every page load ?

Comment: yeah, actually it doesn't "check", it just runs if it is and change de html.class accordingly.